# Trouble with JSON return in Android

Tags: java, android, json, toast

I am having an issue with what my JSON returns in the toast. The toast is there to let me know that the query was successful. The problem is that the toast is triggered, meaning that the query was successful, but it does not contain anything more than Success []. A successful query is supposed to come back as Success [JSON RESULTS HERE].

--

Update: I am getting org.json.JSONException: No value for league at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354) when I run logCat.

What could be happening? Does anyone have any solutions?

**JSON**

```
{"version":"1.0","leagues":{"league":[{"homeURL":"http://www.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/18752","name":"Northern Wisconsin Premier  FFL","id":"18752"},{"homeURL":"http://www.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/36678","name":"Central Wisconsin Fantasy Football League","id":"36678"},{"homeURL":"http://www.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/37766","name":"On Wisconsin","id":"37766"},{"homeURL":"http://www.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/49677","name":"Wisconsin's Premier Dynasty Football League","id":"49677"}]},"encoding":"ISO-8859-1"}
```

**Main activity**

```
public final static String BaseUrl="DUMMYURL";
 ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD> deptList=new ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD>();

 private class GetDeptAyncTask extends AsyncTask<Hashtable<String,String>,Void,String>{ 
  // Parse in background
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Hashtable<String,String>... params) {
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  Hashtable ht=params[0];
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  String json=HelperHttp.getJSONResponseFromURL(BaseUrl+"ENDOFDUMMYURL", ht);
   if(json!=null) parseJsonString(deptList,json);
   else {
    return "Invalid Company Id";
   }
    return "SUCCESS";
 }
 // Parse JSON
 protected void parseJsonString(ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD> deptList,String json) {
  try {
   JSONObject top = new JSONObject(json);
   JSONObject leagues = (JSONObject) top.get("leagues");
   JSONArray array = (JSONArray) leagues.get("league");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
     DEPT_HOLD d = new DEPT_HOLD();
      d.two = j.optString("name","");
      d.one = j.optString("id","");
       deptList.add(d);
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 } 
 // Execute post
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  if("SUCCESS".equals(result)) {
   Toast.makeText(LeaguesTemporary.this, "Success "+deptList.size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   DeptArrayAdapter adapter=new DeptArrayAdapter(LeaguesTemporary.this,R.id.text1,deptList);
   ListView listv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
   listv.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
  else{}
 }    
}
```

**Toast**

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success "+deptList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**DEPT_HOLD.java**

```
public class DEPT_HOLD {

public String two;
public String one;

}
```

**DeptArrayAdapter**

```
public class DeptArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DEPT_HOLD>{

private Context context;
ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD> dataObject;
public DeptArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD> dataObject) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, dataObject);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView=convertView;
    if(rowView==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

    }
    TextView textView  = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    textView.setText(""+getItem(position).one);
    textView1.setText(""+getItem(position).two);

    return rowView;
}

}
```

**HelperHttp**

```
public class HelperHttp {

public static HttpClient httpclient;

private static List<NameValuePair> buildNameValuePair(Hashtable<String, String> httpPost){
      if(httpPost==null) return null;

      List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
      Enumeration<String> keys=httpPost.keys();
      while(keys.hasMoreElements()){
             String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
             String value = (String)httpPost.get(key);
             BasicNameValuePair nv=new BasicNameValuePair(key,value);
             nvps.add(nv);
      }

      return nvps;
     }


private static String buildGetUrl(List<NameValuePair> params, String url){
      String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
      if(!url.endsWith("?"))
             url += "?";

      url+=paramString;
      return url;
     }

public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {
    if (httpclient != null)
        return (DefaultHttpClient) httpclient;
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    // Create and initialize scheme registry 
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(
            new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));


    ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);        

    return (DefaultHttpClient) httpclient;
}



public static String getJSONResponseFromURL(String url, Hashtable<String, String> httpGetParams){
      String json_string="";
      List<NameValuePair> nvps=buildNameValuePair(httpGetParams);
      url=buildGetUrl(nvps,url);
      System.out.println("URL==>"+url);
      InputStream is = null;
      try{
           HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
           HttpResponse response = getThreadSafeClient().execute(httpget);

           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),8192);
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
         json_string=json_string+line;
        }
        response.getEntity().consumeContent();
        System.out.println("Json Response==>"+json_string);
      }catch(Exception e){
           Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
           return null;
      }
      return json_string;
     }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting the json string response?

Comment: I can't be sure. If I wasn't getting a response I would think that my toast would read "Success" instead of "Success []"

Comment: no, its not the case, the reason why its printing `[]` is because its a type `List`. It has nothing to do with json response string. I think you should toast your **json** right after calling `HelperHttp.getJSONResponseFromURL` and see if the web method really returns some string

Comment: I triedToast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success "+deptList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();, Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success "+deptList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();, and Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success "+json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); but the app would crash at that point.

Comment: yes, you cant toast on non-UI thread and doInBackground runs on a separate thread. Instead, try printing the json string in LogCat using `Log.i`, that should work from anywhere.

Comment: I get org.json.JSONException: No value for league at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354).

Comment: that simply means your json string is null, incomplete or not as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

your string comparison is incorrect. Instead of

```
result=="SUCCESS"
```

use

```
"SUCCESS".equals(result)
```

(or better even, return a boolean)

Comment: did you try a step-by-step debug ?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by returning a boolean?

Comment: (instead of return "SUCCESS", put return true, and modify your asynctask so the result type is boolean)

Comment: I get org.json.JSONException: No value for league at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the comparison issue (identified by @njzk2) I think you are forgetting to print the size of your list.

Change:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success "+deptList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success "+deptList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thank you. That didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: I am getting "Success 0" now instead of "Success []", which I was getting when I posted this question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used == to test String equality, and "SUCCESS" shared the same constant String, so you always get the fake True result. Try result.equals("SUCCESS") and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:-

```
      try {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject jLeagues = jObject.getJSONObject("leagues");
        JSONArray jLeague = jLeagues.getJSONArray("league");

        deptList = new ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jLeague.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jl = jLeague.getJSONObject(i);

            deptList.add(new DEPT_HOLD(jl.getString("name")));
            deptList.add(new DEPT_HOLD(jl.getString("id")));
            deptList.add(new DEPT_HOLD(jl.getString("homeURL")));

        }

        StringBuilder totalDept = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < deptList.size(); i++) {
            DEPT_HOLD dept = deptList.get(i);
            String value = dept.getName();

            totalDept.append(value + ",  \n");

        }
        Toast.makeText(ExampleJSONActivity.this, "success " + totalDept,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

DEPT_HOLD:-

```
public class DEPT_HOLD {
    private String name;

    public DEPT_HOLD(String name) {
        super();

        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you said and I am getting this "Success: 0." Would you mind taking a look at my updated code? Do you see anything that could be causing this to still not work? http://pastie.org/7812987

Comment: It looks like one problem is that the URL I am trying to query is invalid because the hashtable is converting to ascii. The URL is supposed to be http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=leagueSearch&JSON=1&SEARCH=crazy, but it is being converted to http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?%3FTYPE%3DleagueSearch%26JSON%3D1=%26SEARCH%test. Do you know how I can prevent the hashtable from converting the URL? http://pastie.org/7813128

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in the size. One person suggested adding that, but I really wanted all of the retrieved content of "deptList" to show up in the toast. Would having ".size()" prevent this from happening?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I applied it to my app and am still getting the same result (Success 0). I had to change the DEPT_HOLD string to public so it wouldn't create an error when it was used on the DeptArrayAdapter page.